# TypeScript Generic sub type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is that possible to pass a namespace as a generic and later access types from the namespace? I would like to achieve something like that:

```
namespace Test {
  export type A = { ... }
  export type B = { ... }
}

type Gen<T> = (a: T.A, b: T.B) => void;

// using Gen<T>
let x: Gen<Test>;
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. But maybe you can elaborate on why you would like to do that to begin with? What's your real scenario?

Comment: I am building an app using Angular2 and Apollo. I am using a `gql-gen` to generate types. It generates a namespaces per query, and inside it adds `Result` and `Variables` types. I would like to use those in my generic type which uses both `Result` and `Variables` and was hoping to do `Cast<UpvotePostMutation>` instead of `Cast<UpvotePostMutation.Result, UpvotePostMutation.Variables>`.
Too bad it's not possible, but thanks for clarifying :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure that I understand you, but if I do, then how about this:

```
namespace Test {
    export const Result = {
        num: 3
    }

    export const Variables = {
        str: "string"
    }
}

interface MyNamespace<R, V> {
    Result: R;
    Variables: V;
}

function Gen<R, V>(namespace: MyNamespace<R, V>): void {}

Gen(Test);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20Variables%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20str%3A%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyNamespace%3CR%2C%20V%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Result%3A%20R%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Variables%3A%20V%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20Gen%3CR%2C%20V%3E(namespace%3A%20MyNamespace%3CR%2C%20V%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0AGen(Test)%3B))

---

#### Edit

You can do something similar with the `query` function you want:

```
function query<R, V>(namespace: MyNamespace<R, V>, data: { query: any, variables?: V }): Array<R> {
    return [];    
}

// type of arr is { num: number; }[]
let arr = query(Test, { query: "query", variables: { str: "" } });
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20Result%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20Variables%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20str%3A%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20MyNamespace%3CR%2C%20V%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Result%3A%20R%3B%0A%20%20%20%20Variables%3A%20V%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20query%3CR%2C%20V%3E(namespace%3A%20MyNamespace%3CR%2C%20V%3E%2C%20data%3A%20%7B%20query%3A%20any%2C%20variables%3F%3A%20V%20%7D)%3A%20Array%3CR%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20type%20of%20arr%20is%20%7B%20num%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%5B%5D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20query(Test%2C%20%7B%20query%3A%20%22query%22%2C%20variables%3A%20%7B%20str%3A%20%22%22%20%7D%20%7D)%3B))

Comment: Not exactly what I needed. I wanted to use it like `query(data: {query: any, variables?: Variables}): ApolloQueryObservable<Result>;` so `Variables` and `Result` are separate.

Comment: Yea, but this is still passing both R and V generics :P. I was hoping to pass just their container and "unpack" them inside ;).

Comment: You are not "passing" any generics, the compiler infers that on its' own based on the "container" namespace.